# Wrapping a template in another template

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

I have a pair of class template declarations like this:

```
template<typename T, template<typename W> class X>
struct B {
    bool operator()(const T& left, const T& right)
    { return X<W>()(left, right); }
};

template<template<typename T> class X, typename Q>
struct A {
   bool operator()(const int a, const int b)
   {
      return B<Q, X>()(a, b);
   }
};
```

I can create `A<std::greater, int>`, `A<std::less, int>` and it works as I want.

Is it possible to create a class that will contain a template passed in like `std::greater` and still  be able to be passed like `std::greater` itself in the example above?

Something like this:

```
template <template <typename T> class Class>
class Wrapper
{
   operator()(const int, const int) { return Class<?what's here?> (value, value); }
};
```

I would like to pass my `Wrapper` to an unchanged `A`

```
A<Wrapper<std::less>, long>
```

In other words, I want to imitate a template passed to my wrapper, to be compatible with actual version of class `A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no, not quite like you want it to be. The first argument of `A` must be a template name. But when you add arguments and write `Wrapper<std::less>`, you get a class type. It is no longer a template. Think of it this way, `A` expects a cookie cutter, but you pass a cookie made from the cutter instead.

That's not to say you can't turn a template into another template, but it won't be quite so opaque. The solution is to add a *member* template to `Wrapper`. Then `Wrapper<std::less>`, despite being a class type, will have a member that is a template. And you can pass that in to `A`.

```
template <template <typename T> class Class>
struct Wrapper
{
   template<typename U> // member template
   struct temp {
     bool operator()(const int v1, const int v2)
     { return Class<U>()(v1, v2); }
   };
};
```

This enables you to write `A<Wrapper<std::less>::temp, long>`.

Check it out [live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aBEIV3T2B5aOvSfq).